# Xcode 8 view object library list hides behind the bar

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I founded an error in storyboard in Xcode8. In Inspector area in show library bar "Show the File Template library" and "Show the Code Snippet library" buttons are working properly. But when I click "Show the Object library" button I see that first item of the list is partially hidden behind the buttonbar. Why top margin there is not working properly and how I can solve this issue?

[image: Show the File Template library]

[image: Show the Object library]

Comment: Fill a problem at http://bugreport.apple.com/ (or http://radar.apple.com/). Once done, duplicate your report at http://www.openradar.me/.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue with storyboard. Might be cursor moved with your hand due to that its appearing like that.

[image]

Comment: No it hides even if there is only one item in list. It seem that top margin or something like that isn't working on Object library tab.

Comment: If u think u can raise a support query in apple forums.